# How do I create an ASP.NET website to search MLS or IDX listings?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create an ASP.NET website to search [MLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Listing_Service) or [IDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Data_Exchange) listings for a real estate website? I'm assuming there is a C# library to do this?  I'm curious about any pitfalls or unexpected expenses people have ran into in using these services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David, every REALTOR belongs to a local area real estate board.  In your case the Greater Lansing Association of Realtors aka GLAR.

There is a standard for moving this data called RETS Real estate transaction standards however not all programs the local boards use support it.  Or, in the case of GLAR they do not enable it.

So often times you have to work directly with the CSV files that they provide to you nightly that you can access via FTP.  They will often provide files for each major type of listing. Vacant properties, condos, residential etc.

You also have to download the images nightly. You can schedule a pull of all the data which is usually huge, and then schedule nightly 'incremental' updates each night.

It is quite a bit of work managing what is new, updated etc. so plan on that.

Also there is usually IDX data and VOW data.  IDX you can show to all website visitors, VOW data you have to have them login with a verified email address.

Hope that helps, we have a half a dozen websites we have done that work with real estate data all in C#

Comment: RETS is not an open standard. You would have to get permission from each "local" realtors board. This is impossible for developers in practice... In short, the Realtor's Board have this info "sewn up".

Comment: Right, some of the Realtor boards will be very open and give their data out and share it in an easy to access manner like RETS.  But, we have found that most boards don't like giving out any data so they make it as difficult as possible and share as little as they can get away with without their members going completely crazy.

Answer (score 2):

David,  Most Real-estate boards have or are implementing [RETS (Real Estate Transaction Standards)](http://www.rets.org/).  The way this is implemented is Using Web Services.   However there is a catch.  Most Real-estate boards will not allow anyone to read and redisplay the information freely [(Broker Reciprocity)](http://www.chicagohomeestates.com/info/broker_reciprocity).  In most cases to read and/or Write to the Real Estate Boards Web Services you need to be either a Broker, Realtor or a Registered 3rd party affiliate.

It is also of note some real estate board do provide DATA dumps of the MLS data to their realtors.  Normally in CSV and it is normally a huge file.

Just for starters here is a link to the [Columbus Board of Realtors](http://columbusrealtors.com/Membership/member_types.aspx) and their Membership Process